# Get time.localtime for each day in a month

Tags: python, time

I'm very new to Python. I'm trying to run a for-loop that will print out the time for each day of a certain month. The range of the loop is the number of days in the month that I'm interested in.

Here is what I have:

```
import time
from calendar import monthrange
num_days = monthrange(2019, 2)[1] # num_days = 28
print(num_days) # Prints 28

for i in range(num_days):   
    print(str(time.localtime()[1]))
```

What do I need to feed to time.localtime as a parameter to print out each day of that 28 day month?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
import bpy
import time
import datetime
from calendar import monthrange
num_days = monthrange(2022, 4)[1] # num_days = 30
print(num_days) # Prints 30

for i in range(num_days):
    mytime = datetime.datetime(2022, 4, i+1).timestamp()
    print(str(time.localtime(mytime)[2]))
```